# How can i concatenate a string to a file name in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following in powershell to rename

```
$version = "2.1.1.1"
```

But i want to make a copy or rename in the same directory as

```
myprogram_2.1.1.1.exe
```

The below doesnt work

```
Rename-Item -Path "C:\myprogram.exe" -NewName "myprogram.exe" + $version
```

Any help with this ?

Comment: add to the `.BaseName`, not to the entire name [including the extension]. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$version = "2.1.1.1"
$NewName = (Get-Item "C:\myprogram.exe").Basename + "_" + $version + (Get-Item "C:\myprogram.exe").Extension
Rename-Item -Path "C:\myprogram.exe" -NewName "$NewName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Rename-Item -Path "c:\myprogram.exe" -NewName "myprogram${version}.exe"
```

When including a variable in a double-quoted string without trailing spaces, you can use ${variable} to enclose it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
Rename-Item -Path "C:\myprogram.exe" -NewName "myprogram_$version.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
$version = '2.1.1.1'
dir myprogram.exe | rename-item -newname { $_.BaseName + $version + $_.Extension } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: 
C:\Users\js\myprogram.exe Destination: 
C:\Users\js\myprogram2.1.1.1.exe".
```